# Ruby on Rails renderin a view with static script files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

In my ruby on rails application I have controlled called AnimalsController. At this controller I have a method "edit" and a corresponded edit.html.erb view in my animals folder. When I also manually added some static javascript file into the page which are located at public/assets/js/ folder. When I render the view, instead of rails is trying to load these javascripts file in the relative path instead of mydomail.com/assets/js/ folder.

Url:
    /animals/:id/edit

I have script file myscript.js inside assets/js/

When I send request to htt://0.0.0.0:3000/animals/:id/edit

Rails search for http://0.0.0.0:3000/animals/:id/edit/assets/js/myscript.js

I want it to seach the script at http://0.0.0.0:3000/animals/js/myscript.js

This is code is in my edit.html.erb

```
<script src="assets/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Not: I intentionally don't use <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`<script src="/assets/js/myscript.js"></script>`

Without the starting '/' it assumes the asset path is rooted on the page path.
With the starting '/' it assumes the asset path is rooted at the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [the rails helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag), it will handle this for you.

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'myscript' %>
```

Just don't forget to add this file to the assets initializer `config/initializers/assets.rb`.